# asp.net core post api always receive null

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, angular6

Here is my angular 6 code

```
saveQuestion(value : string) : Observable<string> {
    console.log(value)
    let params = new HttpParams();
    params = params.set('id', value);
    return this._http.post<string>(this.subjectAPi + 'api/Question/Save/', {params});
}
```

below is my .net core code

```
[HttpPost("[action]")]
public IActionResult Save([FromBody]string id)
{
    Question ob = new Question();
    ob.update(id)  // id is always null
    return Ok("1");
}
```

ID is always null. Suggestion will be really appreciated

Comment: try postman to decide if it is angular or asp issue, if you post using postman you get it as null?

Comment: You're confusing `HttpParams` (which is used for setting query-string parameters) and the POST body (which is the second parameter to `post<string>(...)`. How do you want want to send the ID? As a string body or as a query-string value?

Comment: @KirkLarkin, I want to send it as string body. But if you can provide me example of both then it will be really helpful. I would like to know about the both. thanks

Comment: @yahya Hussein. I can send value successfully by using postman

Comment: Use [fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to look what Angular send to API. And make changes in Angular code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HttpParams is for preparing URL encoded parameters, if you'd like to post a body in JSON you don't need that. Try just simply create your data like:

```
let body = { id: value }
this._http.post<string>(this.subjectAPi + 'api/Question/Save/', body);
```

If you really want to post your body as URL encoded data try to set the Content-Type request header:

```
this._http.post<string>(this.subjectAPi + 'api/Question/Save/', params.toString(), {
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
});
```

Comment: it gives the following error HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 415, statusText: "Unsupported Media Type"                                                                    
while adding 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'

Comment: If you'd want to use the form data, could you please remove the `[FromBody]` attribute, or replace it with `[FromForm]`?

Comment: I have already tried this one but no luck. Just for information, i can send id from postman. but from angular 6 i always get null

Comment: sorry my mistake.. I used body.toString() intead of params.toString() so...... 
this._http.post<string>(this.subjectAPi + 'api/Question/Save/', params.toString(), {
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
});
This really helped me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaking, ASP.NET Core does ***not*** work with camelCasing for JSON by default. Try renaming the `id` in the `HttpParams` to be `Id`.

```
saveQuestion(value : string) : Observable<string> {
    let params = new HttpParams();
    params = params.set('Id', value);
    return this._http.post<string>(this.subjectAPi + 'api/Question/Save/', {params});
}
```